# Add and remove class with action in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i add class by clicking and remove after second clicking.

```
<header id="header" class="header-vertical dark">
```

I want to add 'open' to class section when pressing like 2nd example

```
<header id="header" class="header-vertical dark open">
```

Thanks for support :)

Comment: `$('#header').click(function(){$('#header').toggleClass('open')})` http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: Read the documentation for jQuery..... https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/

Comment: What did your research for “how to add a class in jQuery” and “how to add a click listener in jQuery” yield? What code do you currently have?

Comment: I want add click listener.

Comment: So read the documentation on click().....

Answer (score 0):

Use the `toggle` method! Go like this:

```js
var header = document.getElementById("header");

header.addEventListener("click", myFunc, false);

function myFunc() {
   header.classList.toggle("active");
 }
```

```css
.normal {
  background-color: red;
}

.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunc()">click here</button>
<h1 id="header" class="normal">The Header</h1>
```

And in your case, just replace `.active` with your class, `.open`

Comment: Note that this isn’t jQuery anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Toggleclass, is what you are looking for